# unable to print parameters in ArcGIS and arcpy

Tags: arcpy

I am beginner and created a python script tool in ArcMap and run to print input variables. I also opened python window in ArcMap. The script has not printed the variable values which entered in the tool at run time. Please suggest me.

import arcpy

fc = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

dist = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

print fc

print dist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use 
`arcpy.AddMessage(fc)`  rather than `print(fc)`

ref:
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-functions/addmessage.htm

Comment: Hi, Thanks, If I need to take numeric input, can i use GetParameterAsText, if yes what should be set as parameter type in python script tool, Is it Long or Linear Unit

Comment: Specifically, i want to take input of extent in decimal degree, how should i take ?

Comment: from the arcgis help it states:  Any value regardless of the parameter data type will be returned as a string; to use the parameter as an ArcPy or Python object instead, see GetParameter.